# How do I switch between windows in c on linux with gtk3

Tags: c, linux, gtk3

I have a c application running under linux 
it has one window which loads on startup  ( window 0 )
it is supposed to call any one of 4 windows ( window 1 - 4 )

my problem is I cannot figure out how to call the secondary window and switch to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

in S0.glade I have 4 buttons each calls a diff routine that is supposed to load one of the 4 windows.

I am just not sure how to do it.  I have been googling for 3 days and have not come up with what I need.  Tried alot but no luck.
this is my first attempt at anything with gtk.   Just moving overfrom VB.net under windows and am lost...

my code looks like this  in my main loop

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    GtkBuilder      *builder; 

    /* init threads */
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "S0.glade", NULL);
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "S1.glade", NULL);
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "S2.glade", NULL);
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "S3.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Mini"));

    g_lblStatus1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lblStatus1"));
    g_lblStatus2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lblStatus2"));
    g_lblStatus3 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lblStatus3"));
    g_lblStatus4 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lblStatus4"));

    g_T1_Size = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "T1_Size"));
    g_T2_Size = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "T2_Size"));
    g_T3_Size = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "T3_Size"));
    g_T4_Size = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "T4_Size"));
    g_T5_Size = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "T5_Size"));
    g_T6_Size = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "T6_Size"));

    g_S_1_Status = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "S_1_Status"));
    g_S_2_Status = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "S_2_Status"));
    g_S_3_Status = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "S_3_Status"));
    g_S_4_Status = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "S_4_Status"));
    g_S_5_Status = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "S_5_Status"));
    g_S_6_Status = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "S_6_Status"));

    g_P_1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "P_1"));
    g_P_2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "P_2"));
    g_P_3 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "P_3"));
    g_P_4 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "P_4"));
    g_P_5 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "P_5"));
    g_P_6 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "P_6"));

    g_V_1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "V_1"));
    g_V_2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "V_2"));
    g_V_3 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "V_3"));
    g_V_4 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "V_4"));
    g_V_5 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "V_5"));
    g_V_6 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "V_6"));

    g_CSLN = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "CSLN"));
    g_CBLN = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "CBLN"));
    g_CS_Volume = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "CS_Volume"));
    g_CB_Volume = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "CB_Volume"));

    g_Q_1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Q_1"));
    g_Q_2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Q_2"));
    g_Q_3 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Q_3"));
    g_Q_4 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Q_4"));
    g_Q_5 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Q_5"));
    g_Q_6 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Q_6"));

     // Images
    g_img1 = (GtkImage *)gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img1");
    g_img2 = (GtkImage *)gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img2");
    g_img3 = (GtkImage *)gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img3");
    g_img4 = (GtkImage *)gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img4");
    g_img5 = (GtkImage *)gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img5");
    g_img6 = (GtkImage *)gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img6");
    g_img7 = (GtkImage *)gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img7");

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
        g_object_unref(builder);
        gtk_widget_show(window);                

        Set_Filler_Images();

        gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I want it to call say window 1 from the button on S0.glade and have it active.
the coding I showed is common to S1, s2, and S3 glade files.

Comment: You should consider using [GtkStack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html). Also, you should have a `GtkMenu` and connect the item click/select callbacks to a function that sets the visible child of the stack. I have written an answer [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html)   on how to do it with `Gtkmm/Gtk::Builder`. Hope that helps too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [gtk_widget_show_all](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-show-all) in [signal handler](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.60/howto-signals.html):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void clicked(GtkWidget* sender, GtkWindow* window)
{
    gtk_widget_hide(gtk_widget_get_toplevel(sender));
    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    GtkButton* button1, *button2, *button3, *button4;
    GtkWindow* window1, *window2, *window3;
    GtkLabel* label1, *label2, *label3;
    GtkBox *box1, *box2, *box3;

    window1 = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL));
    window2 = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL));
    window3 = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL));
    //----------------------------------------------------
    button1 = GTK_BUTTON(gtk_button_new());
    g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clicked), window2);
    button2 = GTK_BUTTON(gtk_button_new());
    g_signal_connect(button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clicked), window3);

    box1 = GTK_BOX(gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0));
    label1 = GTK_LABEL(gtk_label_new("splash"));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box1), GTK_WIDGET(label1));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box1), GTK_WIDGET(button1));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box1), GTK_WIDGET(button2));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window1), GTK_WIDGET(box1));
    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window1));

    //----------------------------------------------------
    button3 = GTK_BUTTON(gtk_button_new());
    g_signal_connect(button3, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clicked), window1);

    box2 = GTK_BOX(gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0));
    label2 = GTK_LABEL(gtk_label_new("window1"));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box2), GTK_WIDGET(label2));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box2), GTK_WIDGET(button3));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window2), GTK_WIDGET(box2));

    //----------------------------------------------------
    button4 = GTK_BUTTON(gtk_button_new());
    g_signal_connect(button4, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clicked), window1);

    box3 = GTK_BOX(gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0));
    label3 = GTK_LABEL(gtk_label_new("window2"));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box3), GTK_WIDGET(label3));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box3), GTK_WIDGET(button4));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window3), GTK_WIDGET(box3));

    //----------------------------------------------------
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```